# How do I make the keyboard appear and the text field begin editing when the view is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I am trying to make it so that when the user touches the `UIView` the keyboard appears and the user can type in the textField. I am unable to make the view a first responder how can I make this possible?

Below is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!
    var isKeyboardShowing:Bool = true
    var viewTapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -500).isActive = true
        viewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewWasTapped))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapped)


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.becomeFirstResponder()
        print("Can the view be the first responder: \(self.view.canBecomeFirstResponder)")
        print("the searchbar is the first responder: \(searchBar.isFirstResponder)")
        print("the view is the first responder: \(self.view.isFirstResponder)")
    }

    @objc func viewWasTapped(){
    print("The view was tapped")
        if isKeyboardShowing{
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboardWillShow")
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
        print("keyboardWillHide")
    }

}
```

Comment: `searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to make `self.view` the first responder. You want to make `searchBar` the first responder.

And there is no reason to call `resignFirstResponder` on one view if you are going to call `becomeFirstResponder` on another view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -500).isActive = true
        searchBar.delegate = self

        let viewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewWasTapped))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapped)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

        print("Can the view be the first responder: \(self.view.canBecomeFirstResponder)")
        print("the searchbar is the first responder: \(searchBar.isFirstResponder)")
        print("the view is the first responder: \(self.view.isFirstResponder)")
    }

    @objc func viewWasTapped(){
        print("The view was tapped")
        if searchBar.isFirstResponder {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        } else{
            searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```

Also, `searchBar` isn't the best name for a `UITextField`.

No need for `viewTapped` to be a property. Make it a local variable.

No need for the `isKeyboardShowing` property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post it simplifies the logic much more.